# What do apple refer to as the object graph in the context of Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In their tutorial they say

> "When you fetch objects from a persistent store, you bring temporary
>   copies onto the scratch pad where they form an object graph"

What do they exactly mean by "Object Graph"? Can I maybe log this graph so it will be clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Object Graph" refers to the fact that although CoreData can be used as a database storing a collection of records and is implemented on top of such a database, it is really much more than that.  It manages, stores, and reloads, a complex graph (in the math sense, a bunch of entities with arbitrary connections) of objects with arbitrary relationships.

It's not a "graph" in the sense of a graph in Excel, it's a graph in the stricter sense of a set of objects with arbitrary connections.

Comment: so essentially when I fetch an object let's say I created a fetch request like this  `NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Note"];` will my request hold a set of objects? that have an arbitrary connections to them (by connections you mean the relationships that described in the datamodel? like To Many/To One?)

Comment: It means that you have the option of storing a complex graph in CoreData without a lot of additional work.  Since a single object is just a degenerate graph, you can also store/recover single objects using CoreData.  And yeah, in this case I mean relationships in the CoreData modeler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concept not only related to Core Data but to **Object Oriented programming** in general. Here I quote the [Cocoa Core Competencies documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectGraph.html) (in bold relevant parts).

> In an object-oriented program, **groups of objects form a network
>   through their relationships with each other—either through a direct
>   reference to another object or through a chain of intermediate
>   references**. These groups of objects are referred to as object graphs.
>   Object graphs may be small or large, simple or complex. An array
>   object that contains a single string object represents a small, simple
>   object graph. A group of objects containing an application object,
>   with references to the windows, menus and their views, and other
>   supporting objects, may represent a large, complex object graph.

To provide an overview of what Core Data is (or not is) I really suggest to take a look to [Core Data Overview](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-overview.html) by *Daniel Eggert*.

Hope it helps.